# Avoiding overlapping datapoints in a "scatter/dot/beeswarm" plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, swarmplot

When drawing a dot plot using `matplotlib`, I would like to offset overlapping datapoints to keep them all visible.  For example, if I have:

```
CategoryA: 0,0,3,0,5  
CategoryB: 5,10,5,5,10
```

I want each of the `CategoryA` "0" datapoints to be set side by side, rather than right on top of each other, while still remaining distinct from `CategoryB`.

In R (`ggplot2`) there is a `"jitter"` option that does this. Is there a similar option in matplotlib, or is there another approach that would lead to a similar result?

***Edit:*** to clarify, [the `"beeswarm"` plot in R](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/%7Eeklund/beeswarm/) is essentially what I have in mind, and [`pybeeswarm`](https://github.com/mgymrek/pybeeswarm) is an early but useful start at a matplotlib/Python version.

***Edit:*** to add that Seaborn's [Swarmplot](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot), introduced in version 0.7, is an excellent implementation of what I wanted.

Comment: In a [dot plot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_plot_(statistics)) these points are already separated in their column

Comment: The wiki definition of "dot plot" is not what I am trying to describe, but I have never heard of a term other than "dot plot" for it. It is approximately a scatter plot but with arbitrary (not necessarily numeric) x labels. Thus in the example I describe in the question, there would be one column of values for "CategoryA", a second column for "CategoryB", etc. (_Edit_: The wikipedia definition of "Cleveland dot plot" is more similar to what I am looking for, though still not precisely the same.)

Comment: Similar question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56347325

Answer (score 63):

Extending the answer by @user2467675, here’s how I did it:

```py
def rand_jitter(arr):
    stdev = .01 * (max(arr) - min(arr))
    return arr + np.random.randn(len(arr)) * stdev

def jitter(x, y, s=20, c='b', marker='o', cmap=None, norm=None, vmin=None, vmax=None, alpha=None, linewidths=None, verts=None, hold=None, **kwargs):
    return scatter(rand_jitter(x), rand_jitter(y), s=s, c=c, marker=marker, cmap=cmap, norm=norm, vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax, alpha=alpha, linewidths=linewidths, **kwargs)
```

The `stdev` variable makes sure that the jitter is enough to be seen on different scales, but it assumes that the limits of the axes are zero and the max value.

You can then call `jitter` instead of `scatter`.

Comment: I really like your automatic calculation of the scale of jitter.  Works well for me.

Comment: Does this work if `arr` contains only zeros (i.e. stdev=0)?

Comment: I had to remove `holds` and `verts` both from the parameters of `jitter()` and from the call of `scatter()` to get this to work in 2020. Hope this helps somebody :).

Answer (score 22):

Seaborn provides histogram-like categorical dot-plots through [`sns.swarmplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.swarmplot.html?highlight=swarmplot#seaborn.swarmplot) and jittered categorical dot-plots via [`sns.stripplot()`](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.stripplot.html?highlight=stripplot#seaborn.stripplot):

```
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style='ticks', context='talk')
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.swarmplot('species', 'sepal_length', data=iris)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

```
sns.stripplot('species', 'sepal_length', data=iris, jitter=0.2)
sns.despine()
```

[image]

Comment: Your examples are not two categorical variables, but one categorical and one numerical (sepal_length).

Comment: @felice The question asked for one categorical and one numerical

Comment: Even the variable names contain the word "category". But I now understand my confusion, thanks.

Answer (score 15):

I used numpy.random to "scatter/beeswarm" the data along X-axis but around a fixed point for each category, and then basically do pyplot.scatter() for each category:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

#random data for category A, B, with B "taller"
yA, yB = np.random.randn(100), 5.0+np.random.randn(1000)

xA, xB = np.random.normal(1, 0.1, len(yA)), 
         np.random.normal(3, 0.1, len(yB))

plt.scatter(xA, yA)
plt.scatter(xB, yB)
plt.show()
```

[image: X-scattered data]

Answer (score 8):

One way to approach the problem is to think of each 'row' in your scatter/dot/beeswarm plot as a bin in a histogram:

```
data = np.random.randn(100)

width = 0.8     # the maximum width of each 'row' in the scatter plot
xpos = 0        # the centre position of the scatter plot in x

counts, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=20)

centres = (edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2.
yvals = centres.repeat(counts)

max_offset = width / counts.max()
offsets = np.hstack((np.arange(cc) - 0.5 * (cc - 1)) for cc in counts)
xvals = xpos + (offsets * max_offset)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
ax.scatter(xvals, yvals, s=30, c='b')
```

This obviously involves binning the data, so you may lose some precision. If you have discrete data, you could replace:

```
counts, edges = np.histogram(data, bins=20)
centres = (edges[:-1] + edges[1:]) / 2.
```

with:

```
centres, counts = np.unique(data, return_counts=True)
```

---

An alternative approach that preserves the exact y-coordinates, even for continuous data, is to use a [kernel density estimate](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) to scale the amplitude of random jitter in the x-axis:

```
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde

kde = gaussian_kde(data)
density = kde(data)     # estimate the local density at each datapoint

# generate some random jitter between 0 and 1
jitter = np.random.rand(*data.shape) - 0.5 

# scale the jitter by the KDE estimate and add it to the centre x-coordinate
xvals = 1 + (density * jitter * width * 2)

ax.scatter(xvals, data, s=30, c='g')
for sp in ['top', 'bottom', 'right']:
    ax.spines[sp].set_visible(False)
ax.tick_params(top=False, bottom=False, right=False)

ax.set_xticks([0, 1])
ax.set_xticklabels(['Histogram', 'KDE'], fontsize='x-large')
fig.tight_layout()
```

This second method is loosely based on how [violin plots](http://matplotlib.org/examples/statistics/violinplot_demo.html) work. It still cannot guarantee that none of the points are overlapping, but I find that in practice it tends to give quite nice-looking results as long as there are a decent number of points (>20), and the distribution can be reasonably well approximated by a sum-of-Gaussians.

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately, the `2` in the `xvals = 1 + (density * jitter * width * 2)` part is a parameter that must be tuned depending on the dataset.  For my data I had to set it to 2000 to see any jitter and to 20,000 to get good dispersion at the densest areas.

Answer (score 7):

Not knowing of a direct mpl alternative here you have a very rudimentary proposal:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from itertools import groupby

CA = [0,4,0,3,0,5]  
CB = [0,0,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,0,5]  

x = []
y = []
for indx, klass in enumerate([CA, CB]):
    klass = groupby(sorted(klass))
    for item, objt in klass:
        objt = list(objt)
        points = len(objt)
        pos = 1 + indx + (1 - points) / 50.
        for item in objt:
            x.append(pos)
            y.append(item)
            pos += 0.04

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim((0,3))

plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Seaborn's swarmplot seems like the most apt fit for what you have in mind, but you can also jitter with Seaborn's regplot:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')

sns.swarmplot('species', 'sepal_length', data=iris)

sns.regplot(x='sepal_length',
            y='sepal_width',
            data=iris,
            fit_reg=False,  # do not fit a regression line
            x_jitter=0.1,  # could also dynamically set this with range of data
            y_jitter=0.1,
            scatter_kws={'alpha': 0.5})  # set transparency to 50%
```

Answer (score 5):

Extending the answer by @wordsforthewise (sorry, can't comment with my reputation), if you need both jitter and the use of hue to color the points by some categorical (like I did), Seaborn's lmplot is a great choice instead of reglpot:

```
import seaborn as sns
iris = sns.load_dataset('iris')
sns.lmplot(x='sepal_length', y='sepal_width', hue='species', data=iris, fit_reg=False, x_jitter=0.1, y_jitter=0.1)
```

Comment: If you want to add something to an existing answer you can edit that, if that answer is okay, then you can add another answer to extend that. ;)

Comment: `x_jitter` is deprecated as of recently.