# Matplotlib: Non-random jitter

Tags: python, r, matplotlib, scatter-plot, jitter

I have read the question [Matplotlib: avoiding overlapping datapoints in a "scatter/dot/beeswarm" plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8671808/5471869) and the question [Adding a scatter of points to a boxplot using matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29779079/5471869) however I would like to generate plots like these generated with R:

[image: R plots]
<sub>(source: [eklund at www.cbs.dtu.dk](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/beeswarm_example_02.png))</sub>

[Here](http://www.cbs.dtu.dk/~eklund/beeswarm/) is the code used for those figures.

I would like to do it with matplotlib but so far I have only managed to use `np.random.normal(i, 0.05)`. The dots separate from each other, but I'd like to have them ordered.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8671808/matplotlib-avoiding-overlapping-datapoints-in-a-scatter-dot-beeswarm-plot/8673200#8673200) does something similar to what I want but my data are float numbers which are very close but are different, therefore the `groupby` function does not work, and I'd like to have the dots symmetric to the center as shown in the plots generated with R shown above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed in the **Edit** of this question [Matplotlib: avoiding overlapping datapoints in a "scatter/dot/beeswarm" plot](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8671808/5471869) and I did not read at the beginning, there is a python package for that kind of plots:

https://github.com/mgymrek/pybeeswarm

And definitely that package does a much better job than the code below.

I modified the code of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8673200/5471869) to accept float numbers and I got something slightly similar to what I wanted. Here is the code:

```
CA = [0,4,0,3,0,5]  
CB = [0,0,4,4,2,2,2,2,3,0,5] 
CC = [0.08423, 4.0078, 0.02936, 0.04862, 3.2105, 3.7796, 1.9974, 1.6986, 1.7443, 1.6615, 1, 1, 1]

lists = [CA, CB, CC]

x = []
y = []
for index1, my_list in enumerate(lists):
    scores_bins = {}
    for index2, score in enumerate(my_list):
        binx = round(score, 1)
        if binx not in scores_bins:
            scores_bins[binx] = []
        scores_bins[binx].append(score)

    for key, val in sorted(scores_bins.items()):
        values = scores_bins[key]
        points = len(values)
        pos = 1 + index1 + (1 - points) / 50.
        for value in values:
            x.append(pos)
            y.append(value)
            pos += 0.05

plt.plot(x, y, 'o')
plt.xlim((0,4))
plt.ylim((-1,6))

plt.show()
```

However, if pos is increased the dots move more to the right instead of just spreading from the center to the right and left...